# please find the solution for this query how can i solve this

Tags: mysql, sql

Input table is below:

```
-------------------
|id    | namesl   |
+------+----------+
|    1 | a        |
|    1 | b        |
|    1 | c        |
|    2 | d        |
|    2 | e        |
|    2 | f        |
-------------------
```

I want to print output like this:

```
1 a b c
2 d e f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` function. Then you use `GROUP BY id` since all the names are grouped by its `id`.

Sample query:

```
SELECT   id, GROUP_CONCAT(namesl SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY id;
```